# Views behind Guillotine Menu Screen gets clicked while clicking on Guillotin Menu items

Tags: android

[image: This is layout for Guillotine Menu] I am using Guillotine Menu https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu-Android . Problem is while clicking on Menu items inside Guillotine Menu screen , it invokes the click of behind screen. I have tried to set root view enabled/clickable false while showing Menu but is not working.How can I achieve this?

code for Guillotine Menu xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cscClr"

    android:orientation="vertical">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/Toolbar"

    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:id="@+id/menu" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_group"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem"
    >

    <ImageView
        style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
        android:text="  Profile"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/track_status"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/track" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
            android:text="  Track Status"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emi_calc"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/calculate"
            android:tint="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
            android:text="  Calculator"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/about_app"
    style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/about" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
        android:text="  About Us"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rate_app"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rate" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
            android:text="  Rate the App"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_app"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/share" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nexa_bold"
            android:text="  Share the App"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_group"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/germania_one"
            android:text="Share the App"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_group"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />
```

This is mainscreen lay where I have placed Menu icon for opening Guillotine Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/head"

        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">



        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/head"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/menu"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="80"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/germania_one"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="   E-Loan"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="26dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/track"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/track"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp12"

                    android:fontFamily="@font/germania_one"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Track Status"/>


            </LinearLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"-->
                    <!--android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"/>-->
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


          <com.tompee.funtablayout.FunTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/head1"
            android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"

            android:layout_height="60dp" />

       </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
       </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your code what have you tried, it will help everyone to help you

Comment: i have used Guillotine Menu code as shown in above github link. Besides this I have tried `if(guillotineMenu.isShown(){rootView.setEnabled(false)}`

Comment: You should show use your `xml` code and image of your layout, please read this [how to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)